# How to trigger EntityListener on an Embeddable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an entity with an `EmebeddedId`. The entity listener (trims whitepace off `Strings` on load) on the the entity is being triggered as expected, the same listener on the id `Embeddable` is not triggered at all.

Am I doing it wrong? How can it be fixed?

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBMITTER_VIEW")
@EntityListeners(TrimListener.class)
public class Submitter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SubmitterPK id;

    @Trim
    @Column(name = "DOC_NAME")
    private String name;
...
```

Embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
@EntityListeners(TrimListener.class)
public class SubmitterPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "LSTORT")
    private String bsnr;

    @Trim
    @Column(name = "LOGIN")
    private String login;
...
```

Listener:

```
public class TrimListener {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TrimListener");

    @PostLoad
    public void repairAfterLoad(final Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException {

        log.debug("trimlistener active");

        final Set<Field> trimProps = getTrimProperties(entity.getClass());

        for (final Field fieldToTrim : trimProps) {
            final String propertyValue = (String) fieldToTrim.get(entity);
            if (propertyValue != null) {
                fieldToTrim.set(entity, propertyValue.trim());
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's plainly ignored because it's not a standard place where JPA 2.0 expects it. According to JPA 2.0 final spec, an entity listener may be an entity, a mapped superclass or a listener associated in one of those (see section 3.5 of the spec):

> A method may be designated as a lifecycle callback method to receive notification of entity lifecycle
>   events. A lifecycle callback method can be defined on an entity class, a mapped superclass, or an entity
>   listener class associated with an entity or mapped superclass

Comment: Thanks, MaDa, Makes perfect sense. I guess I'll have to extend the listener to propagate trimming to the embedded classes.

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted the EntityListener to recursively follow fields that are annotated with `Embeddable`. Now, if an entity uses the listener, all embedded classes are processed as well:

```
public class TrimListener {

    @PostLoad
    public void trimAfterLoad(final Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException {

        final Set<Trimmable> trimProps = getTrimProperties(entity);

        for (final Trimmable trimmable : trimProps) {
            final String propertyValue = (String) trimmable.field.get(trimmable.target);
            if (propertyValue != null) {
                trimmable.field.set(trimmable.target, propertyValue.trim());
            }
        }
    }

    private Set<Trimmable> getTrimProperties(final Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException {

        final Class<?> entityClass = entity.getClass();
        final Set<Trimmable> propertiesToTrim = new HashSet<Trimmable>();

        for (final Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType().equals(String.class) && (field.getAnnotation(Trim.class) != null)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                propertiesToTrim.add(new Trimmable(entity, field));
                // if the entity contains embeddables, propagate the trimming
            } else if (field.getType().getAnnotation(Embeddable.class) != null) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                propertiesToTrim.addAll(getTrimProperties(field.get(entity)));
            }
        }
        return propertiesToTrim;
    }

    private class Trimmable {

        final Object target;
        final Field field;

        public Trimmable(final Object target, final Field field) {
            this.target = target;
            this.field = field;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this Kostja; saved me some time!